# Android on BackPress reach 3rd previous activity using finish() only

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

Activity's flow of run

A->B->C->D

- from D onBackPressed() reach A
- from C onBackPressed() reach B

[image]

I don't want to call `startActivity(new Intent(context, A.class));` by only using  finish.

Comment: Do you handle `onBackPressed` in any of your Activities ? If so, then post what you do in those

Comment: If all these activities A, B, C and D are part of a single task then you should convert them into Fragments instead of Activity. Such scenarios can easily be handle for Fragments.

Comment: When coming into the app from outside, e.g., by clicking a notification, you can construct an artificial backstack using TaskStackBuilder. Possibly that can help solve your problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your response but i recently solved problem with this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

is tricky but you can handle on back press go to d to c with some intent data check this intent data is match which you sent from d if true  call back press fiction hare use same concept till a you will go trough d>c>b>a directly this will not show c or d it will work fast otherwise use simple code on back press.

```
    Intent intents = new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityA.class);
   intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intents);
```

Answer (score 0):

override the onbackpressed() of activity D by,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and from activity C you can use finish() to come to Activity B;

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to override `onBackPressed()` in `D` and cgo back to `A` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Please explain why you don't want to use this method?